# classifying pages and second authentication level pages in Liferay

Tags: authentication, content-management-system, system, liferay, categories

I want to know if i can classify pages in the Liferay CMS, so when i'm creating the page i can have a dropdown menu choosing (Public or Classified)

**if it's Public :** That means that all users on the system can view this page.

**If it's Classified:** It should ask then for second authentication level then if the second authentication level is correct then direct them to the requested page but when the process is finished or cancelled, it should end the second authentication level session and once i'm trying to access the same classified page or another classified page it should ask me again.

Can it be done directly from the Liferay system or i need to do programming inside it?.

Answer (score 0):

If you require protected pages/content (based on user roles), this is already part of Liferay, out of the box.

If you require different levels of authentication (e.g. username/password vs. smartcard), you might want to consider adding a SSO solution that provides the different authentication methods. SSO solutions are interfaced out-of-the-box in Liferay, you probably need a bit of customization to determine the authentication method and map that to some roles that can be checked by Liferay (all permissions in Liferay are tied to a role).

Comment: Actually i'm going to use SSO, but the idea is, categorizing the pages as public and classified, if classified it will take him to the SSO but is it something from LifeRay itself or i need to make some customization in categorizing pages, if you have any link which can help that would be more than great. Thanks

Comment: I don't want to connect the page with the user role, i want the page to be categorized, so when any role enter this specific category which is "Classified" it should ask for the Second authentication whether it will be SSO or another password.

Comment: As permissions in Liferay are modelled through roles, this is what I consider as the best way to implement - it's not mandatory to go that way. If you really want to introduce another concept, you'll have to do this everywhere where it fits - checking roles/permissions would already be done. You can also provide a UI that gives the impression of a categorization (but implement through roles) or completely implement yourself. Coming back to your question: If this is what you want, yes, you need to implement/customize it yourself in code. Try to minimize the amount of code you write.

Comment: Thank you so much for this information, it really helps a lot, then i think if i didn't make it with the User Roles, i will have to write the code by myself. if i have other issues regarding LifeRay i will mention you directly :) thanks for the support.

Comment: No problem - glad to be able to help. One minor side-issue: Please note, that "Liferay" is just one word - there's no camel case, no capital "R" in there. Thanks (as I said: it's minor, but helps - me - reading...)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is provided out of the box in Liferay. In liferay we have public and private pages concept.

To map it to your requirement Every community(Site) in Liferay will have Public and Private pages,

Public Pages = Public pages in Liferay. Guest user can see it.

Private Pages = Classifieds, Needs one to login to see these pages.

I think this is similar to What Mr. Olaf is mentioning as user needs to have set of permissions to see the pages.

Comment: thank you for your answer, i believe what i want to do is running away from the User Roles so i will have to code it by myself inside the system. Thanks for the support if i have any other questions i will ask you directly :D